# Mongoose aggregate match returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with `mongodb` aggregations using `mongoose` and a I'm doubt what am I doing wrong in my application.

Here is my document:

```
{
    "_id": "5bf6fe505ca52c2088c39a45",
    "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -43.......,
            -19......
        ]
    },
    "name": "......",
    "friendlyName": "....",
    "responsibleName": "....",
    "countryIdentification": "0000000000",
    "categories": [
        "5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9"
    ]
    "created_at": "2018-11-22T19:06:56.912Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

At the context of my application I need to search documents by GeoJSON, and I execute this search using `geoNear`. Ok it works fine! But moreover I need to "match" or "filter" specific "categories" in the document. I think it's possible using `$match` but certainly I'm doing the things wrong. Here is the code:

```
CompanyModel.aggregate(
                [
                    {
                        "$geoNear": {
                            "near": {
                                "type": "Point",
                                "coordinates": [pageOptions.loc.lng, pageOptions.loc.lat]
                            },
                            "distanceField": "distance",
                            "spherical": true,
                            "maxDistance": pageOptions.distance
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            categories: { "$in": [pageOptions.category] }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ).then(data => {

                resolve({ statusCode: 200, data: data });

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                reject({ statusCode: 500, error: "Error getting documents", err: err });
            })
```

pageOptions:

```
var pageOptions = {
            loc: {
                lat: parseFloat(req.query.lat),
                lng: parseFloat(req.query.lng)
            },
            distance: parseInt(req.query.distance) || 10000,
            category: req.params.category || ""
        }
```

If I remove `$match` I get all the documents by location, but I need to filter specific categories... I don't believe that I need to filter it manually, I believe it can be possible with aggregation functions...

So anyone can help me with this `mongoose` implementation?

Thanks for all help

Comment: Could you show sample `pageOptions.category` ?

Comment: Yes. I Put in the question right now.

Comment: But I mean sample value like is it `5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9` or `ObjectId("5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9")` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong the question. Categories is an array of Strings.

Comment: So stage like ``{ "$match": { categories: { "$in": ["5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9"] } }}`` works fine in this case so perhaps something is wrong with `req.params.category`, could you check that ?

Comment: @mickl i've checked `req.params.category` but it's OK. `category:"5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9"`

Comment: @mickl if the array is [ObjectId("5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9")] Need I change the `$match` arguement? Could you give me an example? (if possible sure...)

Comment: You can't mix ObjectId with string, so `{ "$match": { categories: { "$in": ["5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9"] } }}` works but `{ "$match": { categories: { "$in": [ObjectId("5bf43af0f9b41a21e03ef1f9")] } }}`will fail cause MongoDB compares types before values

Comment: @mickl thank you for your help, the array is of ObjectId and not of String. I'm so dumb... Could you answer the question for me to tag as the best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB you need to make sure that data type in your document matches the type in your query. In this case you have a **string** stored in the database and you're trying to use **ObjectId** to build the `$match` stage. To fix that you can use `valueOf()` operator on `pageOptions.category`, try:

```
{
    "$match": {
        categories: { "$in": [pageOptions.category.valueOf()] }
    }
}
```